Message conversation still thinks iMessage is turned on when it is actually disabled
I have been using my iPhone with iMessage turned off. I then briefly turned it on and messaged in a conversation to my friend. Now I have turned it off again.
When I try to message in that same text chat I get the error "iMessage needs to be enabled to send this message".
All my other text messages to Android users are still working. I do NOT want to delete this chat because it has a long important chat history.
The chat is still showing that messages thinks it should try to send an imessage...

In addition, text messages from contacts that I iMessaged are not arriving to my phone either.
